# How to stop http redirection to https

Tags: http, https

I'm setting up a test environment that does not support https. The problem is, `http://localhost/simulator.aspx#!/data` keeps redirecting to `https://localhost/simulator.aspx#!/data`.
I have tried the following steps:

1. going to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`and deleting `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`
2. Empty Cache and Hard Reload (https://galaxyinternet.us/google-chrome-redirects-localhost-to-https-fix/)
3. removing cached images and files in `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData`
4. nuking `C:/Users/Appdata/local/Google/Chrome`
5. Checking the `disable cache` in Chrome developer tools> network tab.
6. going to task manager and killing the Chrome process to restart.

This didn't change anything, so I tried it in an incognito window. That didn't work either.
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the application itself isn't redirecting to https? (Using [Chrome's developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network).)

Comment: How do I tell the difference between Chrome redirecting to https versus the application redirecting to https..?

Comment: If the request results in an HTTP Status 301 or 302 and the response headers contain a `Location` header that redirects you to https, then it is the application.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it- I get a 'this site cannot be reached. localhost refused to connect` with the response data failing to upload in the network tab...Edit: updated question to show what I'm seeing

Comment: Try with that Network tool open, to go to the http domain and check the first request that appears in that list.

Comment: O_O you're right. I'm getting a 302 error with the location as https://localhost...

Comment: Well, there you go. It seems that you application is trying to redirect you to https. Can't help you much further, because I have no information about your site's architecture.